# Is is possible to use arcpy statement for multiple fields? e.s. arcpy.Intersect_analysis()

Tags: arcpy

I am new in both coding and GIS. Now I am trying something new for me, which is using the for loop to execute some of the arcpy statement. For example, the Intersect_analysis statement.

Following is the code.

```
------------------------------------------------------
'''
interpretation of the Intersect_analysis statement:
Identity_analysis(in_features, identity_features, out_feature_class, {join_attributes}, {cluster_tolerance}, {relationship})

the one I copy from Arcmap when I did the statement using Arctoolbox:
arcpy.Intersect_analysis("HAWKER_CENTRE #","E:/university/NUS/SEM 2/courses/UD5628 - Sustainable Urban Design and Development/GIS/HAWKER_CENTRE_I.shp","ALL","#","POINT")
'''

# Import and setting worksapce
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "E:\university\NUS\SEM 2\courses\UD5628 - Sustainable Urban Design and Development\GIS"

#List of the names of shp files to execute  
fields = ["SUPERMARKET", "WET MARKET", "SHOPPING MALL", "HAWKER_CENTRE", "FOOD CENTRE", "CONVENIENCE STORE"]

#creating for loop to execute the statement for all the shp files

for i in fields:
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(i "#", "E:/university/NUS/SEM 2/courses/UD5628 - Sustainable Urban Design and Development/GIS/i_I.shp", "ALL","#","POINT" )
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you build a string of fc/layers in the format "roads ; streams " (string with semi-colon.separators), they will all be used together as inputs to the Intersect_analysis tool.  To build that string from your full layer list you can use: "; ".join(fields)

Answer (score 1):

Intersect_analysis requires feature classes as input not fields. Using only fields as input will  not work. Please check the [help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm). There are also some examples at the bottom of the help page.